# How to pass dynamic data source in Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

I am trying to create a lightning component but I don't know how I can pass dynamic data source in lightning component design file.

This is the standard example from the documentation where we can pass comma separated String

```
<design:component label="Organization Object">
     <design:attribute name="filter" label="Custom Filter" 
     description="Please Select a object" 
     datasource="Account,Contact,Lead"/>
</design:component>
```

is there any way so that I can pass dynamic list of items such as object list, Opportunity stages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not currently possible. The datasource attribute of the design file only supports a static list of values.

Providing dynamic picklist support is on our roadmap, but there is no timeline to share at this point [#safeharbor].

Comment: Thanks Eric for your response. I will wait for this feature

Answer (score 0):

As of Spring '17, you can now [build dynamic picklists for lightning page components in Apex](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring17/release-notes/rn_forcecom_lab_dynamic_picklists.htm).

While they are "dynamic", these design attributes cannot [respond to user selections in other design attributes (Vote for the idea)](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CTa2QAG). You might be able to use custom metadata or custom settings to mimic a dependency between items.